OSRM Route vs. Trip with fixed first & last
I noticed that OSRM allows users to define fixed first and last locations for the Trip service. I'm curious whether doing this is equivalent to simply using the Route service.
If they're different, which way is better for generating the shortest (not the fastest) route?
Thanks!
